# AIX 6.1 use svn: libz.a could not be loaded

Tags: svn, aix

when I use svn, the error is:

```
Could not load program svn:
Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib/libsvn_delta-1.so.
    Dependent module /data01/SUGRP/tmpbm/release/lib/libz.a(libz.so.1) could not be loaded.
    Member libz.so.1 is not found in archive
Could not load module svn.
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libsvn_delta-1.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module .
```

but I have added the path(`/data01/SUGRP/tmpbm/release/lib/`) to the `LIBPATH` in `.cshrc` . Why I can't load.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem, and after a lot of research, i found this http://www.justskins.com/forums/solved-dbd-mysql-on-50013.html which solved my problem.

Basically, renaming can solve your problem, even if i don't know why.

Let us know if it worked.